# Welcome file in java

Tags: java, servlets

I don't know how to access the html(fp.html) file under webcontent folder.

Deployed app structure

```
fp(app name)
|__ fp.html
|__ META-INF  
|__ WEB-INF
```

My web.xml has this configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>fp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fp.FpServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FpServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>fp.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

If I access the file localhost:8080/fp/fp.html like this, It shows 404 error.
But accessing localhost:8080/fp/ working fine.

Kindly help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: you need to define the servlet

Comment: where have you placed fp.html , it should directly be placed in your web-content folder

Comment: Unless your app was installed as the server's root app, `localhost:8080/fp.html` won't work, as that would indicate a file in the root app.  The URL should contain the web app's context root, eg `localhost:8080/webappname/fp.html`.  Also, the mapping in your web.xml will trap ***all*** URL patterns and redirect that request to a servlet called FpServlet.  So, unless that servlet exists, you're out of luck again.  If that servlet doesn't exist, just remove the mapping.

Comment: Yes i directly posted under webcontent folder

Comment: Post your full `web.xml` and tell us your folder structure. Probably its a path issue. The servlet mapping is actually irrelevant if its just an html file you are trying to access directly.

Comment: keep your application name in url like this : localhost:8080/applicationname/fp.html

Comment: @DurgaGanesh Just placing the file directly under the `webcontent` folder doesn't mean you won't need to prefix your path with the name of your web application.

Comment: @fvu Hussain Akhtar Wahid      localhost:8080/webappname/fp.html url doesn't work

Comment: @DurgaGanesh Post also how your folders are structured. Could be some simple spelling mistake or case issue in the URL.

Comment: configure ur port number to something else say 8081

Comment: @DurgaGanesh how do you deploy your app?  Also, `webappname` is merely an example, you should replace it with the actual name of the application, or context root if you override it via web.xml or deployment.  Or did you just throw all files in some subdir of you Tomcat installation directory?

Comment: @fvu if i change the url pattern /fp/fp.html i can access the file and localhost:8080/fp/fp.html works fine. but accessing localhost:8080/fp/ doesnt work

Comment: @DurgaGanesh does that `FpServlet` actually exist?  Also note that what you say in your last comment is the exact opposite of what you say in you question.

Comment: @DurgaGanesh How do you expect ppl to help you if you don't give the full info. First you say you can't access it, then you say you can and its something else. Clarify what is exactly the problem, no one knows what is your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Tomcat can host multiple applications. So in general your folder structure would look something like this:

`~/<yourtomcatfolder>/webapps/<yourapplication>`

You put any HTML files you want to access directly under that folder, which means you can then access the file like this:

`http://localhost:8080/yourapplication/fp.html`

Obviously the port and everything is configurable, so the above is just an example. You put also any CSS and JS files similarly, and you can have sub-folders.

Then you put your classes (servlets etc.), libraries etc. under the special WEB-INF folder under your application's directory.

`~/<yourtomcatfolder>/webapps/<yourapplication>/WEB-INF/classes`
`~/<yourtomcatfolder>/webapps/<yourapplication>/WEB-INF/lib`

Anything under `WEB-INF` is not accessible from outside (so no one can download your class files and decompile them etc.)